# Swift append gives missed argument error

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

My code was fine before adding color: `UIColor` into my existing class. After adding color: `UIColor` append part of my code is giving error (missing ',' argument).

I have pasted only part of my code. Please see bottom line for error.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class DestinationType {

    var name: String                    // name of destination type
    var destinations : [Destination]    // all destinations in the type

    init (name:String, includeDestination:[Destination]) {
        self.name = name
        self.destinations = includeDestination
    }

    class func destinationTypes() -> [DestinationType] {
        return [self.summer(), self.winter()]
    }

    private class func summer() -> DestinationType {

        var destinations = [Destination]()

        destinations.append(Destination(name: "Antalya", description: "Very", imageName: "antalya.png", color: UIColor.greenColor)
```

// Expected ',' seperator
        }

If you need, find my class file below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Destination {

    var name : String
    var description : String
    var image : UIImage
    var color : UIColor

    init (name:String, description:String, imageName:String, color:UIColor) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        if let img = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            image = img
        } 
        else {
            image = UIImage(named: "default")!
        }
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`greenColor` misses the parentheses. It needs to be `greenColor()`.

Swift's error messages are more misleading than giving any good hint to what is wrong :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
destinations.append(Destination(name: "Antalya", description: "Very", imageName: "antalya.png", color: UIColor.greenColor)
```

That line has two `(` and only one `)`

Comment: Indeed, but that's not the main cause (probably a copy/paste error)